# Why does a line starting with "-->" not throw an error in Javascript?

Tags: syntax, console.log

Consider the following three lines of Javascript.

```js
console.log(1);
--> console.log(2);
console.log(3);
```

I would expect it to cause a `Syntax Error`, probably something like `Unexpected token --`.

Instead, browsers seem to accept the code, and simply ignore the second line, producing the output:

```
› 1
› 3
```

I've tried pasting the snippet into the consoles of Chrome, Safari and Firefox. All of them behave the same way. What's going on?

Comment: @Pointy Which context specifically? Works everywhere I've tried, including Node.js

Comment: It does behave the same in Node.js (v8.9.4) when I run it from a .js file (`node index.js`)

Comment: Well it was failing for me (10.15.0) but in any case you found the (surprising, to me) rule in the grammar. I'm sure it's there for ancient code, though it seems like an extremely nasty oddity that could really ruin one's day :)

Comment: Deleted my incorrect comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently ECMAScript officially allows ["HTML like" comments](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-html-like-comments):

> **B.1.3 HTML-like Comments**
>
> The syntax and semantics of 11.4 is extended as follows except that this extension is not allowed when parsing source code using the goal symbol Module:

```
HTMLCloseComment::
    WhiteSpaceSequence opt  SingleLineDelimitedCommentSequence opt  -->  SingleLineCommentChars opt
```

Which suggests that whatever comes after `-->` should be treated as a comment.

Comment: Ah and it fails in Node because of that caveat at the top of that section. Good find!

Answer (score 3):

It is part of a HTML comment for older browser with the pattern to have Javascript parts in browsers who do not support the `<script>` tag.

```
<script>
<!--

// some code 

-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Messing around with the console seems to prove Nina's case

```
-->
   undefined
typeof -->
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
--> = "foo"
   undefined
-->
   undefined
--<
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
<--
   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
<!--
   undefined
<!-- foo -->
   undefined
```

It seems that these keywords are set to always return undefined.